# Intersection between line segment and a plane

Tags: geometry

Is there a very simple test to check if a line *segment* in $3D$ space cuts a plane? 
It is assumed we have the coordinates of the endpoints of the line segment, so $p_1,p_2$ and that we have the equation of the plane: $z = d$ (so for simplicity we're assuming it's a plane orthogonal to the z-axis).

Comment: You mean "parallel" to the $z$-axis? In any case, can't you just plug in the points $p_1$ and $p_2$ into $ax+by$, and if one is bigger than $d$ and one is smaller than $d$, then the segment passes through the plane.

Comment: @Nick hi, thanks. So in a simpler case, where the plane is orthogonal (I made a mistake in the post) to z, say we have the plane $z=4$, then we just check if $p_1(z), p_2(z)>4$, right?

Comment: You'd want one of the points to have $z$-coordinate $\leq 4,$ and the other to have $z$-coordinate $\geq 4.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Represent the plane by the equation $ax+by+cz+d=0$ and plug the coordinates of the end points of the line segment into the left-hand side. If the resulting values have opposite signs, then the segment intersects the plane. If you get zero for either endpoint, then that point of course lies *on* the plane.

You can get the coefficients of the plane equation from a normal vector $\mathbf n$ and a point $\mathbf p$ on the plane via the point-normal form of the equation: $\mathbf n\cdot(\mathbf x-\mathbf p)=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I may ask 1-2 questions: i) why do we have different signs if the segment given by the two endpoints cuts the plane? ii) regarding the equation, as a simple example to sanity check: we have a rectangular plane with the z-axis orthogonal to it, and we know the plane cuts the z-axis at $z=4$. So a normal vector would be: $(0,0,4)$ and a point on the plane we can take the intersection of z-axis and plane, so $(0,0,4)$, so the Eq. of plane is $z=4$, right? Many thanks in advance

Comment: Unpack $\mathbf n\cdot(\mathbf x-\mathbf p)$: subtracting $\mathbf p$ translates so that the origin is on the plane. With $\mathbf x'=\mathbf x-\mathbf p$, $\mathbf n\cdot(\mathbf x-\mathbf p)=\|\mathbf n\|\,\|\mathbf x'\|\cos\theta$, so the sign depends only on the angle between the vectors: if positive, $\mathbf x'$ is on the same side of the plane as $\mathbf n$; if negative, they’re on opposite sides of the plane. For the segment, if its endpoints are on the same side of the plane, then there’s no intersection. And yes, that’s an equation of your example plane.

Comment: BTW, if you have a lot of points to test, just use the l.h.s. of the normal equation: $\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf x-\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf p$. You only need to compute the second term once, so it’s three multiplications and three additions per tested point.

Answer (score 0):

So the plane is given by $ax + by + 0z -d = 0$ Using the parametric form - you must find the line equation in each direction. E.g $x=t, y=2+3t, z=t$

Then you plug that into the plain eq.: $a(t) + b(2+3t)0 + 0(t) - d = 0$. Take that value and plug it in for $t$ in the 3 equations given for the line.

Eg. Let $a=2, b=1, d=7$ (we dont care about $c$) then the plane is given by $2x +1y -4 = 0$ and plugin for line: $2(t)+1(2+3t)-7=0 => t=-1$ and solution is: $(-1,-1,-1)$

If there is one solution thats the intersection, $0t = k$ for constant $k$ there is no solution - and the line is parallel, and if $0t = 0$ all values for $t$ is a solutions for $x, y, z$ and the line is on the plain.